# To be + verb+ed

Tags: meaning

**To be investigated inside the house is one of my unforgettable moment**
Would you like explain the sentences?
One of my teacher says "to be" followed verb+ed always express future meanings

Comment: No, the *be* indicates the passive voice (the action is not performed by the speaker but done to the speaker by someone else). The past participle (i.e, plain form of verb +  *ed*) indicates completed action, but not when that action happened. You could say "To be investigated inside the house **was** one of my unforgettable moments." But you couldn't know that unless the investigation happened in the past. Can you get another teacher?

Comment: That means "To be investigated inside the house was one of my unforgettable moments and To be investigated inside the house is one of my unforgettable moments" express same meanings?

Comment: You can rely on the investigation to have taken place in the past because it being unforgettable happened in the past ("**was** unforgettable").  Not so for "is unforgettable," which you could say as the police ransack your house right now.